# Unable to get products based on attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to retrieve products based on attributes. What I am trying to do is

https://somedomain.com/someapp/wp-json/wc/v2/products?Attributes=Recommended

But. I can't able to access the data.

I have gone through so many links. But, I did not find anything related to me.

[image]

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Product attributes are not very suited for what you are looking for, they are designed to be *Parent to Child* relations so only serve best when providing a way to populate the extra information tab on product pages, and provide a mechanism for the generation of product variations. As such you will not be able to achieve (without a huge work around) what you want using this method.

However if all you wish to do is filter by a word, then you should really be looking at Product Tags as they are designed for this sort of thing. Take a look under `Products -> Tags` for the area in question.

Happy Coding!

Koda

Comment: help me how to do that using `tags`. Because, I can't get data using tags too.